# failed to run android when trying to add android platform to cordova app

Tags: cordova

Hi all I've been trying for days to get cordova to work. I have installed java jdk, android studio and apache ant. when I go to a cmd prompt and type javac the output indicates it is installed fine, when I type ant -version. that also indicates that it is installed fine.

I have added a variable setting for ANDROID_HOME = **C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin** and also added it to path in the system variables. I have also added just the path to to the android studio without the bin dir.

but every time I run the command

```
cordova platform add android
```

I keep getting the error Failed to run "android" make sure you have the latest version of android sdk installed.

Can anyone help?

Comment: you need android sdk, not android studio

Answer (score 2):

You will need to download the android SDK. Once you have this downloaded you will need to add both `\android-sdk\tools` and `\android-sdk\platform-tools` to your environment variables path.

You **do not need** to add the android studio to your path.

Also it may help to make note, that the target api for the latest version of cordova is 19, so make sure to install this as well as the latest api to avoid any further errors.

Comment: And you'll also need to install apache-ant.